# Sort Set of Numbers in the form (XX-YY) in Python

Tags: python, sorting, natural-sort

I have a python list that contains values that follow the form

CCXX-YY where CC is 2 alphabetical characters that are the same for all values, X is an integer and YY are also integers.

e.g.

```
KA13-1 KA13-2 KA14-2 KA14-1 KA11-12 KA13-11
```

into

```
KA11-12 KA13-1 KA13-2 KA13-11 KA14-1 KA14-2
```

and not

```
KA11-12 KA13-1 KA13-11 KA13-2 KA14-1 KA14-2
```

Things I have tried:

natsort (issue with thinking the - is a negative sign)

Late edit: natsort works if you use the parameter alg=ns.UNSIGNED, as noted below.

naturalsort (doesn't work with python 3?)

sort using a key value (I'm sure this can be done, but I'm a bit new to python and am failing at it)

Things I'm currently trying:

Removing all the extra fields besides the numbers and attempting to sort based on that (this has some issues because KA12-10 will come after KA14-1 as it'll be 1210 compared to 141)

I cannot easily change the values to not include dashes as I am pulling the data from a request to a website and need the values to be in the original form to query individual items.

I'm sure someone that has more experience manipulating the built-in sort could help me out.

Thanks.

Comment: What is your sort priority? `C` first then `X` then `Y`? Or only sort by considering `X` then `Y`?

Comment: Considering your example, wouldn't a string sort be sufficient? Also, please specify what you mean with values. Are your values strings, classes, arays on their own?

Comment: @Pinna_be , the values were strings, similar to the ones in the example. String sort was not sufficient because it would put KA13-11 before KA13-2, which is not what the desired result was.

Comment: @Cyber Sort priority is X then Y, C is the same for all the items so its irrelevant for the sort, but I just added it in to conform to my problem more.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ISTM the real question is where you'd want something like `KA13-12` to go.  If you want it to come after `KA13-2`, then I think you need something like

```
>>> seq = "KA13-1 KA13-2 KA14-2 KA14-1 KA11-12 KA13-12".split()
>>> seq.sort(key=lambda x: tuple(map(int, x[2:].split("-"))))
>>> seq
['KA11-12', 'KA13-1', 'KA13-2', 'KA13-12', 'KA14-1', 'KA14-2']
```

Comment: Great, this fixed it. Thanks for the help. I figured it would be something with the key and a lambda, just couldn't figure out how to do the lambda correctly.

Answer (score 3):

Your desired sort output is just lexicographic ordering.  Just use [`sorted`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#sorted)/[`list.sort`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#typesseq-mutable) without any custom key or comparer.

Comment: Except when I do list.sort, it was doing it wrong. It would go thru the XX values and then sort thru the YY values because of the first 2 alphabetical characters. Let me try again.

Comment: @JoeBradish: How are you calling `sort`?  If I do `sorted("KA11-12 KA13-1 KA14-1 KA13-2 KA14-2".split())`, I get `['KA11-12', 'KA13-1', 'KA13-2', 'KA14-1', 'KA14-2']`.

Comment: Ok, this makes me think its something within my list values that is throwing off sort, because when I'm using regular sort on the list I have, it is doing something like KA13-1 KA14-1 KA13-2 KA14-2 except with the "KAXX-YY" being a list of my data.

Comment: How do you know that the OP wants lcg?  The given example would sort the same under lcg order and (string, int0, int1), no?

Comment: Okay, here is what is going wrong. I just had a poor example (which I'll fix after this).  If you were to add KA13-10 to the data set, it'll appear after KA13-1, but before KA13-2. This is where my issue is and why I can't just do LCG ordering.

Answer (score 1):

If you only want to consider the integer portion for the sort:

```
l = ['KB13-1', 'KA13-2', 'KC11-11', 'KA14-1', 'KA11-12']
sorted(l, key=lambda i: i[2:])
```

Output

```
['KC11-11', 'KA11-12', 'KB13-1', 'KA13-2', 'KA14-1']
```

If the first two characters, never change, then you can just use the plain vanilla `sort` or `sorted` functions.

```
x = ['KA13-1', 'KA13-2', 'KA11-11', 'KA14-1', 'KA11-12']
sorted(x)
```

Output

```
['KA11-11', 'KA11-12', 'KA13-1', 'KA13-2', 'KA14-1']
```

Answer (score 1):

**UPDATED ANSWER**

As of [natsort](https://pypi.org/project/natsort/) version 4.0.0, this will work for you right out of the box, without having to use and special options.

```
>>> from natsort import natsorted
>>> natsorted('KA11-12 KA13-1 KA13-11 KA13-2 KA14-1 KA14-2'.split())
['KA11-12', 'KA13-1', 'KA13-2', 'KA13-11', 'KA14-1', 'KA14-2']
```

---

**OLD ANSWER** for natsort < 4.0.0

You mentioned that [natsort](https://pypi.org/project/natsort/) did not work for you because of negative signs. This is because by default '-' is interpreted as part of the following number, but you can disable this with the "UNSIGNED" modifier.

```
>>> from natsort import natsorted, ns
>>> natsorted('KA11-12 KA13-1 KA13-11 KA13-2 KA14-1 KA14-2'.split(), alg=ns.UNSIGNED)
['KA11-12', 'KA13-1', 'KA13-2', 'KA13-11', 'KA14-1', 'KA14-2']
```

Using `versorted` would work also.

```
>>> from natsort import versorted
>>> versorted('KA11-12 KA13-1 KA13-11 KA13-2 KA14-1 KA14-2'.split())
['KA11-12', 'KA13-1', 'KA13-2', 'KA13-11', 'KA14-1', 'KA14-2']
```

Full disclosure, I am the `natsort` author.